# Backup .sql from laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, backup

I'm going to backup my database .sql file from laravel. when I use artisan command from cmd, the backup file will generated with no issue. but when i do that from controller I got this error.

How to fix this?

> mysqldump: Got error: 2004: "Can't create TCP/IP socket (10106
>   "Unknown error")"

Comment: Can you share your code block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [db-dumper](https://github.com/spatie/db-dumper) package to backup your database.

Installing:

```
composer require spatie/db-dumper
```

Usage:

```
Spatie\DbDumper\Databases\MySql::create()
    ->setDbName($databaseName)
    ->setUserName($userName)
    ->setPassword($password)
    ->dumpToFile('dump.sql');
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. but now I'm getting this error Misuse of shell builtins : mysqldump: Got error: 2005: Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost' (2) when trying to connect

Comment: are you sure your config are correct in config/database.php  file  or .env file

Comment: Yes! the thing is its working when i browse it from "localhost/myapp/public/backup". but when i run it from artisan "localhost:8000/backup"  I got this error. why is that?

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/db-dumper/discussions/165


This gives me the above error.